# How to click on a menu with svg tag on it using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to click on a menu button using selenium, but isn't working using WebDriverWait or any other way. How can i click on it using selenium from https://www.dappradar.com/binance-smart-chain/defi/drip here

```
<div class="apexcharts-menu-icon" title="Menu"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z"></path><path d="M3 18h18v-2H3v2zm0-5h18v-2H3v2zm0-7v2h18V6H3z"></path></svg></div>
```

Comment: Which element is that? What have you tried so far?

Comment: My bad, wrong code. I need to click on the drop down menu titled "Menu" and than click on one of the options. Tried using .click(), .send_keys() , None worked so far. I am new to selenium , so there might be something i did wrong

Comment: `menu = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#apexchartsjkga8jbaf > div.apexcharts-toolbar > div.apexcharts-menu-icon > svg"))
menu.click() `

Comment: got it, please see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SVG` is wrapped inside `div` tag, so you can either locate `SVG` or `div`.

I can do it with `div`:

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://dappradar.com/binance-smart-chain/defi/drip")

try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Close']"))).click()
    print('Clicked on closed icon')
except:
    pass

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@title='Menu']"))).click()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it in Java, so what I do is first I scroll to particular location where our desired element exist (somewhere in the bottom). then apply implicit wait so our desired element is ready to be clickable then click on it.

```
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(100));
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(50));
        driver.get("https://dappradar.com/binance-smart-chain/defi/drip");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,350)", "");

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div[title='Menu']")));
        System.out.println("Button enabled:  " + driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[title='Menu']")).isDisplayed());
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[title='Menu']")).click();

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("div[class='apexcharts-menu apexcharts-menu-open']")));

        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class='apexcharts-menu apexcharts-menu-open'] > div"));

        System.out.println("List size  " + elements.size());
```